# Efficient way to get "neuron-edge-neuron" values in a neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I'm working on a visual networks project where I'm trying to plot several node-edge-node values in an interactive graph.

I have several neural networks (this is one example):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 2)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(2, 3)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(3, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = self.fc1(x)
        x = torch.relu(x1)
        x2 = self.fc2(x)
        x = torch.relu(x2)
        x3 = self.fc3(x)
        return x3, x2, x1

net = Model()
```

How can I get the `node-edge-node` (`neuron-edge-neuron`) values in the network in an efficient way? Some of these networks have a large number of parameters. Note that for the first layer it will be `input-edge-neuron` rather than `neuron-edge-neuron`.

I tried saving each node values after the `fc` layers (ie `x1,x2,x3`) so I won't have to recompute them, but I'm not sure how to do the edges and match them to their corresponding neurons in an efficient way.

The output I'm looking for is a list of lists of `node-edge-node` values. Though it can also be a tensor of tensors if it's easier. For example, in the above network from the first layer I will have 2 triples (1x2), from the 2nd layer I will have 6 of them (2x3), and in the last layer I will have 3 triples (3x1). The issue is matching nodes (ie neurons) values (one from layer n-1 and one from layer n) with the corresponding edges in an efficient way.

Comment: In what form do you seek the final output and what is your current approach ?

Comment: "The output I'm looking for is a list of lists of `node-edge-node` values". Though it can also be a tensor of tensors if it's easier. My current approach is to theoretically iterate through each `fc` layer matrix and somehow match the edges with the corresponding start node (from the previous layer) and end node (from the next layer), but I couldn't get it to work (and I'm not sure that it's an efficient way to do that

Comment: Do you gurantee that your network has only Linear layers and they are always in cascaded fashion ?

Comment: .. and what about the bias term ? does it come under your `node-edge-node` structure ? I don't think so. Is it important ?

Comment: @ayandas you can ignore the bias

Comment: @Penguin See my answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Confession:** Let's start by saying that I modified your code a bit to make it convenient. You can do everything in the form it originally was. I also changed the specific number of neurons just for playing around (I am sure you can revert them back).

I created a `summary` object (returned by `.forward()` function) that contains entire *execution trace* of the network, i.e. `(input, weight, output)` tuples for *every layer.

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3, 5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(5, 7)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(7, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        summary = []
        running_x = x
        for layer in self.children():
            out = layer(running_x)
            # triplet of (input, weight, output) for each layer
            summary.append((running_x, layer.weight, out))
            running_x = out

        return summary

model = Model()
batch_size = 32
X = torch.rand(batch_size, 3)
summary = model(X)
```

The core logic is only this much

```
for L in summary: # iterate over the (ip, weight, out) tuple for each layer
    ip, weight, out = L # unpack them
    
    ip = ip[:, :, None, None].repeat(1, 1, out.shape[-1], 1)
    weight = weight.T[None, :, :, None].repeat(batch_size, 1, 1, 1)
    out = out[:, None, :, None].repeat(1, ip.shape[1], 1, 1)
    triplets = torch.cat([ip, weight, out], -1)
```

So the `triplets` variable (one for each layer) is all you are looking for. It has a size

```
(batch_size, layer_in_dim, layer_out_dim, 3)
```

Let's see specifically the `triplets` for first layer.

```
>> triplets.shape
(32, 3, 5, 3)
```

E.g., given a sample index `b = 12`, input neuron index `i = 1` and output neuron index `j = 3`, you have exactly `node-edge-node` tuples

```
>> triplets[b][i][j]
tensor([0.7080, 0.3442, 0.7344], ...)
```

---

**Verify:** Let's manually verify the correctness.

The `12`th sample's `1`st dimension is

```
# Its the first layer we are looking, so input comes from user
>> X[12][1]
tensor(0.7080)
```

**CHECK.**

The connecting weight between `1`st input neuron and `3`rd output neuron for first layer

```
>> model.fc1.weight.T[1][3] # weight matrix is transposed, so had to do .T
tensor(0.3442, ...)
```

**CHECK.**

The output of `3`rd neuron for `12`th sample can be retrieved from its activation tensor

```
>> _, _, out = summary[0] # first layer's output tensor
>> out[12][3]
tensor(0.7344, ...)
```

**ALSO CHECK.**

---

I hope that's what you wanted. If anymore info/changed needed, feel free to comment. I don't think it can get any more efficient that that.

Comment: Looks good. A few questions: if I wanted to also train this, do I need to return `running_x` along with `summary`? Also, you mentioned that the triplets have a size of `(batch_size, layer_in_dim, layer_out_dim, 3)`, but shouldn't it be more than that? If we're adding all the triplets from all the layers. Unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: If want to have proper gradient w.r.t the `triplets`, you need `running_x`. `summary` already includes all `running_x`.
Also, we have `triplets` for each layer (I mentioned already; see the core logic `for` loop). We can't pack all `triplets` for all layers because they have different dimensions.

Comment: .. so basically we get a list (length = # of layers) of tensors (i.e. `triplets`). I didn't create this list explicitly in my code. I am sure you can do that yourself.

Comment: Different dimensions? Each triplet is of size 3. A bit confused

Comment: No but you have different number of such triplets. You wrote yourself in the question that "2 for first layer, 6 for 2nd layer, 3 for third layer"

Comment: `triplets` for first layer is `(Bx3x5x3)`, second layer is `(Bx5x7x3)` and third is `(Bx7x2x3)`. There is no straightforward way to pack them